# Code analysis using visual studio extension

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Is it possible to write an extension which will do code analysis? I looked at the api and I didnt see how I can get all variables that are declared in the document/xref on specific variable and get it flow in the code. If someone know api in visual studio code which actually helps with it, it will be great.

Comment: have a look at how PyLint does the linting, It use a module that builds an AST and uses that to generate the errors

Answer (score 0):

Creating such an extension is certainly possible, however you have to do your own language processing. AFAIK there's no way to access the internal structures (syntax tree, symbol table etc.) of the existing JS/TS (or other language for that matter) extensions.